# SQL Server Select Parent-Child + COALESCE ( Join )

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child, coalesce

I have the following tables:

**1. table Language**

- Id (varchar) (PK)
- Description (varchar)
- System (bit)
- ParentId (varchar) FK to Id

Example: 
[EN, English, 1, NL] , [NL, dutch, 1, null] , [FR, french, 0, EN]

**2. table enumExample**

- Id (int)
- Description (varchar)

Example: 
[1, Bla] , [2, blabla] , [3, blablabla]

**3. table enumExampleTranslation**

- LanguageId (PK, FK to Language)
- EnumExampleId (int, PK, FK to enumExample)
- Value (varchar)

Example: 
[EN, 1, Blo] , [NL, 1, bloblo]

**4. view: vwExampleView**

- LanguageId (varchar)
- Id (int)
- Description (varchar)

Example: 
[EN, 1, Blo] , [NL, 1, bloblo]. [FR, 1, blo]

The question is about the view:

- The Language table holds a hierarchy of language so e.g. EN (is parent of) XE ( is parent of) YU
- The table enumExampleTranslation holds sometimes values so e.g. it could hold the EN translation but not the XE translation and also not the YU translation of a certain enum.(or the EN and the XE translation but not the YU translation).
- The view... should show always a translation but if there is no translation for YU for a certain value then it should take XE if that has no value it should take EN if that has no value it should taket the enumExample description.

a. so for getting the chain of languages from the language table i could

```
Declare @TABLEVAR table (id nvarchar(3) ,parentid nvarchar(3))
;with parents as (
   select Id, Parentid from Language where Id = 'UK'
   union all
   select c.Id, c.ParentId from Language c
   join parents p on p.ParentId = c.Id 
)
INSERT INTO @TABLEVAR
select *
from parents
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

But now in the view I have do something like but then with no null values but a sort of select inside a coalesce:

```
 Select t1.id, g.EnumExampleId, (select top(1) i.Value from   
 EnumExampleTranslation i where i.EnumExampleId = g.EnumExampleId )    
 as Description 
 FROM @TABLEVAR t1 FULL OUTER JOIN
 EnumExampleTranslation g on t1.id = g.LanguageId
```

This last query (or the view definition) I want to get to work. But i have some trouble getting the @TABLEVAR values in there.

Comment: ah slip of the tag: sql server

Comment: A sample data would be much easier to understand the logic and also to mimic the dilemma  that you need to solve.  Also, a question, if there is no translation for XE, does the value for that will be always NULL ?

Comment: if there is no translation for XE in enumExampleTranslation then it will not be null, there is no record in there then for XE. In the view it should then show the parent value (if there is one)

Comment: we would love to help you, only if you corporate and provide us with actual samples to work with and not `Example: [1, Bla] , [2, blabla] , [3, blablabla]` these won't give you nor us any good results.